# Melbourne: Traveling from Southern Cross station to hotel at 11 PM

Tags: public-transport, night-transport, melbourne

Taking the SkyBus to the Southern Cross Station, then was wondering, the shuttle service there, does it get you to any hotel or apartment hotel? How can I find out?

I need to reach the corner of La Trobe and Queen street, at a late hour, and trying to avoid a Taxi if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here
https://www.skybus.com.au/free-city-hotel-shuttle/participating-hotels/

Basically the shuttle gets you to a lot of hotels, and it works around the clock.

Comment: Just thought of adding a note, that I arrived at about 10:30 PM, the point of sale was closed, and there were no shuttles to be found, I took a taxi.